# Controller with Index action with optional parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to have an Index action for a "Users" controller that takes an optional parameter.

```
/Users/{id}
```

Or

```
/Users
```

I'd like to avoid:

```
/Users/Index/{id}
```

Or

```
/Users/Index/
```

I added a Route to map /Users/{id} to the Index action.

```
routes.MapRoute( "Users",
                 "Users/{id}",
                 new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id =
                 UrlParameter.Optional});
```

That works fine.  I ran into a problem when I added another action, "Add", also with an optional parameter, to the Users controller.  The route I added earlier misinterprets Add as a parameter to the Index action.  The "Index" action gets triggered for /Users/Add.

How can I get the best of both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the *constraints* property to only allow numbers.  That should fix your routing issue.

```
routes.MapRoute( "Users",
    "Users/{id}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { id = "[0-9]+" }
);
```

*Edit*.

You can do it differently without using a regex constraint.  Add the route *Users/Add* explicitly, adding it **before** the *Index* route:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Users",
    "Users/Add/{id}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Add", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: @JoelSkrepnek indeed I do not.  Please see my edit.  You can always "hard wire" the routes like this; the key is to put the more specific ones first.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see how this goes over with the boss :).

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to create routes for each action on your controller. A default route that is in global.asax at the beginning of creation of a project is enough for your needs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: I created the route to avoid /Users/Index/{id}.